# Set size for a tag

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list **li** and **a** inside, even though I set a tag's **`width: 100%`**, **`display: block;`**, but somehow the **`a`**'s text gets cut by **`li`**'s size, and the actual size of **`a`** is bigger than **`li`**.

I think it is, because of the **`padding`** making the **`a`** tag area bigger than **`li`**'s size, but I'm not sure. I want the **`a`**'s size to fit the **`li`** and if the text is too long it must break to the next line.

Please help me, because it is in wordpress so I can not post all the code here because its very long, hope you can give me suggestion to fix this. Thank you

[image]

Comment: We need an example of your problem. Try to recreate it with minimal code. You can use [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `word-break: break-all;` to the `li` item.

```
li {
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work as well, but only if I set the specific width for a but I don't understand, it just not practical

Comment: @pexichdu see updated answer. try to test with `break-all;` instead of just `break;`